# How to use ssh with slirp to reach out Internet from a limited jump server?

Tags: linux, ssh, route, nat, tunneling

Sorry that I might be wrong, yet I have some impressions from QEMU that SLIRP has the ability to do both ppp server and NAT stunt the same time.

The situation is, I'm under a very limited network environment, yet the organization which I work for provides a "jump server" which could reach out the Internet.

The sshd_config on that jump server prohibits tunneling, and thus the "ssh -D" socks server trick won't cut.

Currently, I have fired up a ssh connection and let pppd on my local machine to do its PPP tasks with the ssh-allocated pty :

```
sudo pppd nodetach noproxyarp noauth pty \
"ssh -t jump_server /path/to/slirp -P " \
netmask 255.255.255.0 connect-delay 5000
```

Then, I add a route rule to test the connection :

```
sudo ip route add <some_telnet_server> dev ppp0
telnet some_telnet_server
```

However, the telnet fails.
After tearing down the connection, SLIRP log said it received some packets yet it barely transmitted packets. So I guess it's a configuration issue ?

Yet I'm struggling to understand how to configure SLIRP to NAT my connection.
(It seems that QEMU modifies slirp very heavily ?)

Is there any cheat sheet for such purpose ?
I have searched and read several articles[1][2][3], yet none of them mentions the details of NAT/routing configuration.

[1] https://jdimpson.livejournal.com/3330.html

[2] https://workhorselaboratories.net/ssh-ppp-and-slirp/

[3] https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Firewall-Piercing/x189.html

Comment: It sounds like you're asking us to help you bypass a deliberate security control at an organization you work at.  What is your intent here?

Comment: The intent is to fetch building dependencies. The jump server is provided for that reason. Yet it's painful to use. The ITs asked workers to wget stuffs on that machine.

Comment: It sounds like the approved method is wget and that tunnels, of any kind, are intentionally prohibited.  Security policy is rarely convenient, but it may be there for good reasons.

Comment: slirp can only do NAT and will do it naturally: it will use the available BSD socket API on the host to initiate the actual connections to "outside". so when you initiate a TCP connection to 192.0.2.2, slirp will "route" it by opening a TCP connection to 192.0.2.2 (using system calls such as socket() and connect() and not even bind() so source port isn't preserved).